# Can not start Kestrel with Http2And3 together

Tags: c#, .net

my dear friends. I'm testing some GRPC features based on net 5.0

I'm trying to start the Kestrel server (for self-hosting approaches) like bellow:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel((options) =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(lo => lo.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3);

                }).UseUrls("http://localhost:5000");
            });
```

I'm facing an error that I could not find on Stackoverflow or other communities:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start HTTP/3 server if no IMultiplexedConnectionListenerFactory is registered.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)

Anyone can help?

Comment: Seems Http3 support will come with 6.0: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15271#issuecomment-702896688